# Constructing the automorphism group from the normalizer in a representation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $ H $ be a finite group. Act $ H $ on itself via the left regular representation to get $ H \to GL_n $ where $ n=|H| $. Then $ N_G(H)/C_G(H) $ is a group of automorphisms of $ H $, where $ G=GL_n $.

EDIT: As pointed out by verret, every automorphism is just an element of $ X=S_n $ which is naturally inside $ G=GL_n $. Thus $ N_X(H)/C_X(H) = {\rm Aut}(H) $ and so certainly $ N_G(H)/C_G(H) = {\rm Aut}(H) $.

Is there some other way to find an irrep $ \pi: H \to G=GL_m $ such that ${\rm Aut}(H)\cong N_G(H)/C_G(H) $ but where $ m $ is much less than $ |G| $, for example $ m \leq \sqrt{|G|} $?

Motivation:

Let $ P $ be an extraspecial $ p $ group of order $ p^3 $ of plus type. There is a faithful representation $ P \to GL_p(\mathbb{C}) $ given by sending one generator to the matrix $ X $
$$
X: e_i \mapsto e_{i+1}
$$
where the index $ i $ is taken mod $ p $, and sending the other generator to the diagonal matrix
$$
Z: e_i \mapsto \zeta^i e_i
$$
where $ \zeta $ is a primitive $ p $th root of unity. It turns out that $ {\rm Aut}(P) \cong N_G(H)/C_G(H) $ where $ G= GL_p(\mathbb{C})$. In fact this is true for an extraspecial $ p $ group $ P $ of plus type of order $ p^{2n+1} $ for any $ n $. The representation is defined by viewing $  \mathbb{C}^{p^n}$ as an n-fold tensor product $ \otimes_n \mathbb{C}^p $ and then defining the generators $ X_1 ,\dots, X_n $ and $ Z_1,\dots, Z_n $  on each of $ n $ tensor factors. Again this representation $ P \to GL_{p^n}(\mathbb{C}) $ has the property that ${\rm Aut}(P) \cong N_G(H)/C_G(H) $ where $ G= GL_{p^n}(\mathbb{C})$.

I'm interested in other examples like this. Or perhaps a more general construction that I can view the above example as a case of.

Comment: Inside $GL_n$, you have the subgroup of permutation matrices $S_n$ and $H$ is a subgroup of that. Already for $X=S_n$, it is true that $N_X(H)/C_X(H)=Aut(H)$. (Unless I am misunderstanding your notation...)

Comment: @verret  Now that you mention it I suppose it's pretty obvious that this is already true for $ X=S_n $. So perhaps I'll remove that part of the question and focus on cases like my motivating example where we can do this in a representation of dimension significantly less than $ n=|G| $.